# How does limiting Widget rebuilds exactly influence performance in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I've read about and experimented quite a bit with UI rebuild optimization in Flutter and understand the concepts of how to limit the amount of widgets being rebuilt. However, I am not sure what it actually influences - the widgets are just a 'configuration' tree and they are actually not what is drawn, there is a lot happening after the build phase.

According to this diagram https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/architectural-overview#from-user-input-to-the-gpu layout, paint, composition and rasterization all happens after the build phase. Does this mean that if some portion of the widget tree isn't rebuilt, all of the following phases are also omitted for it?

On the other hand, if a parent widget changes, but its children do not (e.g. because the whole subtree is const), the new screen still needs to be re-composited and redrawn, as the unchanged 'const children' need to be overlaid onto the new parent, and then all of that needs to be rasterized. This would mean only parts of the tree don't need to be built, laid out and painted (which still is a win) but then the whole screen still needs to be composited and rasterized. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: I tried it out and it is as you say, but could you explain why and how it relates to my question? E.g. the only difference between orange and red is that orange Container sizes itself to the child (i.e. doesn't occupy the whole width of the screen) whereas the red Container does - but why does orange influence FooPainter, which is below (in a Column layout) both of them? Same for the EvelevatedButton, it doesn't cover FooPainter.

Comment: Ah, the difference is that orange changes on every build - it needs to lay itself out due to the child (Text showing current date/time) changes every time I tap. Still, I don't yet get what is going on.

Comment: It means that when rebuilding only the subset of your tree rebuild but all the widgets repaint

Comment: Right. And why doesn't repainting happen when I tap red? Is it because no relayouting happened and Flutter recognizes this?